Rendering Latex in markdown in React Native Expo performantly
I am trying to render LaTeX within Markdown in a React Native Expo app performantly while the actual contents of the Markdown/LaTeX is changing or being streamed.
I've not been able to find a package that provides this Markdown and LaTeX rendering. I have been able to find LaTeX packages and Markdown packages, but not one which allows for inline LaTeX. So I'm currently just using WebView, and then I'm using a Mathpix Markdown it script within the WebView. But this is leading to performance issues because I am updating the WebView a lot. Because the Markdown string is being streamed live to the WebView.
And I am quite sure that it's actually downloading the scripting on each text update which is causing a lot of lag, while the text is being streamed.
I've tried using a PostMessage to update the web view, but it doesn't seem to be able to keep up with the speed of the stream. I think the solution may be to try to use a Markdown package and combine it with a LaTeX package by using some sort of custom rendering logic. But I have not figured out how to get a solution like that to work.
Then it is also important for me for the inline latex to support multiple syntaxes so for instance
$2 $
$$2$$
\[ 2 \]
and
\(  24   \)
and then of course just to clarify these inline latex lines should be within the markdown context, so for instance
# heading 1
## heading 2
lists and code blocks and stuff like that should also work.

how do you stream in stuff? via HTTP2/3 or some custom JavaScript?
Either way, I would start with trying pandoc's various output formats. If you're CPU-constrained (which might be the case in a webview on Android) and not bandwidth-constrained, then pre-rendering to SVGs (pandoc -s --gladtex) might be best.
